# Query to find the additional value in a table based on condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table below

| Id | group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 11 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 3 |
| 2 | D | 2 |
| 3 | D | 8 |
| 4 | A | 6 |
| 4 | C | 6 |

I would like to display the result

| Id | value | Additional Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 | 4 |

MySQL Query

```
SELECT id , 
       SUM(VALUE), 
       SUM( CASE WHEN (day_type = 'R' AND (VALUE) > 8) THEN (VALUE - 8) WHEN (day_type = 'R' AND (VALUE) <= 8) THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) AS additional_value 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY id
```

I would like to split the value, into value and additional value, if the value is> 8 I need to add the extra value in the additional value column, My query works for a single row with a value > 8 but with multiple combinations, it does not work.

Could anyone give me a solution for this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to compare the total of value for each id to 8:

```
SELECT id, 
       LEAST(SUM(value), 8) value,
       GREATEST(SUM(value) - 8, 0) additional_value
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1afa460247050baf1fb797a7f27d421).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, It is working, Just a small change in my table structure like if an extra data field is added, I need to get the entire sum of value and additional hours between a date range for the corresponding id. Eg: if id 1 has value 11 on 6th June and value 11 on 7th June, My result would be 1 - 16  - 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`. For example:

```
select
  id, 
  least(sum(value), 8) as value,
  greatest(0, sum(value) - 8) as additional_value
from t
group by id
```